# How to break event.stopImmediatePropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a code like this:

```
<td>
 <span class='ui-button-next'>NEXT</span>
</td>
```

This application contains a library and it is not allowed to be edited. On clicking "ui-button-next", they are calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop something.

I want to call a function when user clicking on this "span" without touching that Library.

My custom code is like:

```
$(".ui-button-next").click(function(){
});

$(".ui-button-next").bind("click",function(){
});

$(".ui-button-next").on("click",function(){
});
```

are not working due to `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` on the library.
any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the underlying events list (array) and insert your new click handler at the first, it will be triggered normally, however note that the order of execution should not be a problem in your case:

```
//this is the inner handler
$('.ui-button-next').click(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();     
});
//this is the handler of your own
$('.ui-button-next').click(function(e){       
    alert('OK');
});

//get click handlers list
var clicks = $._data($('.ui-button-next')[0], 'events')['click'];
//get the last added handler (which is your own handler) and put it at the beginning
clicks.unshift(clicks.pop());
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2j5s8/)

**UPDATE**: To keep the order of execution (the default handlers are executed first, all the additional added handlers are executed after), I think you have to modify the default handlers by removing all the `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` methods, we have to use the `eval()` method here. Note that using that method in this case is totally OK.

```
//get click handlers list
var clicks = $._data($('.ui-button-next')[0], 'events')['click'];
//remove the e.stopImmediatePropagation() in each handler
$.each(clicks, function(i,e){
  var handlerText = e.handler.toString()
                     .replace(/e.stopImmediatePropagation\(\)/g,'');    
  eval("e.handler = " + handlerText);
});
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2j5s8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually order of execution matters. I want to execute this code at last. Because before this, need to populate lot of fields.

Comment: @user3724926 check out my updated demo. It breaks the `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` totally, all the additional handlers added later will be triggered normally.