# how to break event.stopImmediatePropagation on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

While building an extension, a webpage disabled all `eventListener`s and disabled `eventListener`s on my test extension. For example, when the event listner looks like,

```
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 console.log('A click event fired.');
});
```

but the webpage disabled event listener(I can't edit the webpage). As I expect [Event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) fired on all event listeners and keep event listeners from firing events. Like,

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#test');
// From the webpage,
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
console.log('A click event fired.');
});

// From my test extension, 
//this event listener is stopped by e.stopImmediatePropagation();
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
console.log('Extension is executed.');
});
```

```html
<div id='test'>
Click me
</div>
```

And I found a question about [how to break event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134970/how-to-break-event-stopimmediatepropagation). But there is only a solution for jQuery.

I want to find how to break `stopimmediatepropagation` with only javascript. Any comment or answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really for a click event (or at least a bubbling event), you can add a capturing event handler on the document before any script is ran. This will ensure you'll receive the event.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#test');
// From the webpage,
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
console.log('A click event fired.');
});

// From your test extension, 
// make it run before the page's scripts
// to be sure to also catch other "captured" events
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 if( e.composedPath().includes( element ) ) { // check that 'element' has really been clicked
    console.log('Extension is executed.');
 }
}, { capture: true }); // catch it in capture phase
```

```html
<div id='test'>
Click me
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe my question is wrong for misunderstanding the problem. The webpage would cancel event listener without `stopimmediatepropagation`. Thanks for the answer.